# Where to place encapsulated function in other script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Disclaimer: Extremely amateur at JS, I just know how to manipulate it a bit...

So I have two jQuery scripts running. One of them prevents the other from working correctly after using. I remember awhile ago when this happened I had to encapsulate one of them, and then execute it in the next.

The encapsulated code:

```
    var setUpScroll = function(){
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $("body").niceScroll();  // The document page (body)
        $("#mid-col-main-inner").niceScroll();  // Second scrollable DIV

      });
    };
    setUpScroll();
```

The other code (isotope.js)

```
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#mid-col-main-inner');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.sbox'
  });


  var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
      $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

  $optionLinks.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
      return false;
    }
    var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
    var options = {},
        key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
        value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
    // parse 'false' as false boolean
    value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
    options[ key ] = value;
    if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
      // changes in layout modes need extra logic
      changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
    } else {
      // otherwise, apply new options
      $container.isotope( options );
    }

    return false;
  });


});
```

Anyone know where I need to place setUpScroll? And if this will fix it? Please let me know if I need to include any other information.

**EDIT: Disregard encapsulate info. Regardless of it, the scripts are interacting incorrectly...**

Comment: I can see no reason why you would need to do use the `setUpScroll()` encapsulation.  It's already encapsulated in the `$(document).ready()`.  What JS errors do you see in the debug console or error console?  What isn't working?

Comment: Perhaps it's not that then? Here is the page: http://nerdi.net/playground/kev Select the buttons on far left column to sort/animate with isotope. The nice scroll js starts acting really screwy after.

Comment: I don't see or understand what doesn't work on that page.  Please describe how one causes and sees the problem in more detail.  Remember, we don't know your site or know what the expected behavior is.

Comment: Click the 2nd button on left, then the first. It will sort a little, then go back to showing all. After it does that, the DIV becomes unscrollable.

Comment: There are a lot of clickable button things on the left.  Do you mean where is says "jQuery", "lipsum" and "type"?  Click on those?  For me the list isn't scrollable when I first load the page.

Comment: Yes, I mean those. Correct, it's not scrollable on page load. But without the second (isotope) script, it scrolls fine. See here: http://nerdi.net/playground/kev/index2.html

Comment: So your question is really: "Why is my isotope script messing up the ability to scroll my content?".  I don't think this has anything to do with an interaction of two scripts.  The second script is just doing something wrong.  I don't know anything about isotope or know what `changeLayoutMode()` does to know how to help further.

Comment: Thank you for your help! At least I got a little clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create the setUpScroll function unless you want to call it multiple times.

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
(function($) { //jQuery will map to $ now
    self.setUpScroll = function(){
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("body").niceScroll();  // The document page (body)
            $("#mid-col-main-inner").niceScroll();  // Second scrollable DIV

        });
    };
    setUpScroll();
})(jQuery); // <-- pass jQuery to your anonymous function
```

Comment: What's the point of this?  `setupScroll()` is simply not needed.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if you didn't read the comments to the OP, jfriend00 helped deduce it's not about that. Interestingly - on first loading the page http://nerdi.net/playground/kev , and then clicking the "Type" link - you can scroll fine. But not the third, or on the landing page, or anything after that. Very weird.

Comment: yea, ill just leave my answer, but seeing the comments it doesnt answer what you want